# Can't use IActivatedEventArgs

Tags: c#, xamarin.uwp

I can't use `IActivatedEventArgs`  in a `UWP` to get command line options

because I have no reference to `Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation`

because I have no `Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.dll` anywhere on the machine

So where should this .dll be so I can add it to my assemblies?

If it isn't there - how do I get it there?

UPDATE: This project does not appear to be a UWP project after all - it appears to be a Xamarin project that has had everything but UWP stripped out. And I'm guessing you don't get Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation in Xamarin. Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: which version are you using? related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.iactivatedeventargs

Comment: Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134
So I should be plenty late enuff

Comment: also implemented the sdk for the required version?

Comment: Where would I look for this info? It's .Net framework 4.6.2 but I dodn't think that is what you are asking...

Comment: best explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a value in the  .csproj file to edit. Looking at Project properies doesn't show a minimum or target version. I'm so lost...

Comment: you installed the version for UWP or the default one?

Comment: This isn't my project on a machine that isn't mine. New job. Appreciate your patience. I have checked a VS 2017 does have the UWP stuff installed. What version - how do I check?

Comment: sorry for the late response: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackageforuser